# How to put background on the top for internal pages of installer

Tags: nsis

How can I put the background image to the top of internal installer page, so it takes all header area.

In solution below background takes only left side of the header

```
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP "top.bmp"
!include "MUI2.nsh"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP_NOSTRETCH

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without modifying a UI executable. See [the MUI 2 docs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI%202/Readme.html), specifically the `MUI_UI` definition. You'd need to take the default executable and with a resource hacker change the size of that header image.

You may also be able to swing this with resource hacking and the value of MUI_UI_HEADERIMAGE (see those docs). I'm not sure, though, as I've never tried it.